# Center text vertically in a table, very

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, alignment, text, cellsize

I'm trying to center text vertically in a table. I've tried several tips from this forum, but I still can't solve it. I want all the text in the table to be vertically aligned. I'm using this code with this packages

```
\usepackage{array}                      
\usepackage{tabularray}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{table}[H]
        \caption{{\small number}}   
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular} {|c| L{2cm} | C{2cm} | R{2cm} |ll}      
                \cline{1-4}
                number & $h$ (m) & $A$ (m) & $v_{0}$ (m/s) & &  \\[7pt] \cline{1-4}
                1ª      &  &  &  &  &  \\[7pt] \cline{1-4}
                2ª      &  &  &  &  &  \\[7pt] \cline{1-4}
                3ª      &  &  &  &  &  \\[7pt] \cline{1-4}
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \label{tabela1}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: By adding `[7pt]` after `\\\` you destroy the vertical centering.

Answer (score 1):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Number}
\label{tabela1}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{colspec={c*{3}{Q[c,2cm]}},vlines,hlines}
number & $h(m)$ & $A(m)$ & $v_0(m/s)$ \\
1ª     &        &        &            \\
2ª     &        &        &            \\
3ª     &        &        &            \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]